# What Addons are compatible with EE 3.0?

Tags: add-on, wygwam, module, plugin

I am beginning the transition to EE 3.0 and have not been able to find a list of compatible plugins, add-ons, etc. Is there such a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. Devotee has a list [here](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filter?&f=ee3).